# gvim slow to start at "starting GUI" step

Tags: linux, vim

My gvim takes almost 4 seconds to start up / open a file

Here is my `.vimrc`

```
set clipboard=exclude:.*
set backspace=indent,eol,start
syntax on
```

I tried profiling the startup time of "gvim" with `gvim --startuptime`, and here's the output. As you can see, `starting GUI` taking ~4000 msec.

```
times in msec
 clock   self+sourced   self:  sourced script
 clock   elapsed:              other lines

000.013  000.013: --- VIM STARTING ---
000.161  000.148: Allocated generic buffers
000.267  000.106: locale set
000.285  000.018: GUI prepared
000.288  000.003: clipboard setup
000.294  000.006: window checked
000.815  000.521: inits 1
000.839  000.024: parsing arguments
000.842  000.003: expanding arguments
000.873  000.031: shell init
001.535  000.662: Termcap init
001.565  000.030: inits 2
001.685  000.120: init highlight
014.802  000.778  000.778: sourcing /zzz/pkgsrc/share/vim/vim82/syntax/syncolor.vim
014.930  001.783  001.005: sourcing /zzz/pkgsrc/share/vim/vim82/syntax/synload.vim
023.981  000.036  000.036: sourcing /zzz/pkgsrc/share/vim/vim82/autoload/paste.vim
025.618  003.431  003.395: sourcing /zzz/pkgsrc/share/vim/vim82/menu.vim
025.651  009.995  006.564: sourcing /zzz/pkgsrc/share/vim/vim82/filetype.vim
027.335  000.455  000.455: sourcing /zzz/pkgsrc/share/vim/vim82/scripts.vim
027.398  015.195  002.962: sourcing /zzz/pkgsrc/share/vim/vim82/syntax/syntax.vim
027.406  016.010  000.815: sourcing $HOME/.vimrc
027.411  009.716: sourcing vimrc file(s)
034.777  000.087  000.087: sourcing /zzz/pkgsrc/share/vim/vim82/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
035.820  000.233  000.233: sourcing /zzz/pkgsrc/share/vim/vim82/plugin/gzip.vim
037.075  000.228  000.228: sourcing /zzz/pkgsrc/share/vim/vim82/plugin/logiPat.vim
038.121  000.033  000.033: sourcing /zzz/pkgsrc/share/vim/vim82/plugin/manpager.vim
039.008  000.192  000.192: sourcing /zzz/pkgsrc/share/vim/vim82/plugin/matchparen.vim
040.451  000.483  000.483: sourcing /zzz/pkgsrc/share/vim/vim82/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
041.510  000.042  000.042: sourcing /zzz/pkgsrc/share/vim/vim82/plugin/rrhelper.vim
042.329  000.031  000.031: sourcing /zzz/pkgsrc/share/vim/vim82/plugin/spellfile.vim
043.289  000.198  000.198: sourcing /zzz/pkgsrc/share/vim/vim82/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
044.742  000.095  000.095: sourcing /zzz/pkgsrc/share/vim/vim82/plugin/tohtml.vim
045.827  000.194  000.194: sourcing /zzz/pkgsrc/share/vim/vim82/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
046.714  000.215  000.215: sourcing /zzz/pkgsrc/share/vim/vim82/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
046.724  017.282: loading plugins
047.079  000.355: loading packages
047.103  000.024: loading after plugins
047.112  000.009: inits 3
4171.747  000.856  000.856: sourcing $VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim
4420.478  4372.510: starting GUI
4421.496  001.018: reading viminfo
4479.480  057.984: GUI delay
4481.334  001.854: register server name
4481.335  000.001: setting raw mode
4481.336  000.001: start termcap
4481.404  000.068: clearing screen
4481.703  000.299: opening buffers
4481.764  000.061: BufEnter autocommands
4481.768  000.004: editing files in windows
4483.271  001.503: VimEnter autocommands
4483.275  000.004: before starting main loop
4486.013  002.738: first screen update
4486.015  000.002: --- VIM STARTED ---
```

Also below is the profiling of "vim" cmd. It's very fast because `inits 3` step is quite fast.

```
times in msec
 clock   self+sourced   self:  sourced script
 clock   elapsed:              other lines

000.013  000.013: --- VIM STARTING ---
000.160  000.147: Allocated generic buffers
000.808  000.648: locale set
000.827  000.019: GUI prepared
000.830  000.003: clipboard setup
000.836  000.006: window checked
001.621  000.785: inits 1
001.649  000.028: parsing arguments
001.650  000.001: expanding arguments
001.687  000.037: shell init
003.231  001.544: Termcap init
003.262  000.031: inits 2
003.383  000.121: init highlight
009.192  000.935  000.935: sourcing /zzz/pkgsrc/share/vim/vim82/syntax/syncolor.vim
009.319  001.915  000.980: sourcing /zzz/pkgsrc/share/vim/vim82/syntax/synload.vim
015.492  005.353  005.353: sourcing /zzz/pkgsrc/share/vim/vim82/filetype.vim
017.218  000.480  000.480: sourcing /zzz/pkgsrc/share/vim/vim82/scripts.vim
017.273  011.540  003.792: sourcing /zzz/pkgsrc/share/vim/vim82/syntax/syntax.vim
017.281  012.731  001.191: sourcing $HOME/.vimrc
017.286  001.172: sourcing vimrc file(s)
027.845  000.074  000.074: sourcing /zzz/pkgsrc/share/vim/vim82/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
028.844  000.235  000.235: sourcing /zzz/pkgsrc/share/vim/vim82/plugin/gzip.vim
029.716  000.221  000.221: sourcing /zzz/pkgsrc/share/vim/vim82/plugin/logiPat.vim
030.452  000.029  000.029: sourcing /zzz/pkgsrc/share/vim/vim82/plugin/manpager.vim
031.314  000.178  000.178: sourcing /zzz/pkgsrc/share/vim/vim82/plugin/matchparen.vim
032.446  000.480  000.480: sourcing /zzz/pkgsrc/share/vim/vim82/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
033.147  000.042  000.042: sourcing /zzz/pkgsrc/share/vim/vim82/plugin/rrhelper.vim
033.816  000.036  000.036: sourcing /zzz/pkgsrc/share/vim/vim82/plugin/spellfile.vim
034.984  000.177  000.177: sourcing /zzz/pkgsrc/share/vim/vim82/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
035.744  000.099  000.099: sourcing /zzz/pkgsrc/share/vim/vim82/plugin/tohtml.vim
036.629  000.196  000.196: sourcing /zzz/pkgsrc/share/vim/vim82/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
037.544  000.210  000.210: sourcing /zzz/pkgsrc/share/vim/vim82/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
037.554  018.291: loading plugins
037.869  000.315: loading packages
037.893  000.024: loading after plugins
037.913  000.020: inits 3
038.879  000.966: reading viminfo
038.886  000.007: setup clipboard
038.895  000.009: setting raw mode
038.913  000.018: start termcap
038.925  000.012: clearing screen
039.331  000.406: opening buffers
039.363  000.032: BufEnter autocommands
039.367  000.004: editing files in windows
039.470  000.103: VimEnter autocommands
039.472  000.002: before starting main loop
039.822  000.350: first screen update
039.822  000.000: --- VIM STARTED ---
```

Any clue what causes the delay of gvim?

===update===

my gvim version seems same as vim version

gvim `:version`

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Jul 31 2021 22:05:17)
Included patches: 1-3172
Modified by morr@NetBSD.org
Compiled by willsk@ch12ldbld04
Huge version with GTK3 GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               +clipboard         +dnd               +gettext           +listcmds          -mouse_sysmouse    +postscript        -sound             +termresponse      +vreplace
+arabic            +cmdline_compl     -ebcdic            -hangul_input      +localmap          +mouse_urxvt       +printer           +spell             +textobjects       +wildignore
+autocmd           +cmdline_hist      +emacs_tags        +iconv             -lua               +mouse_xterm       +profile           +startuptime       +textprop          +wildmenu
+autochdir         +cmdline_info      +eval              +insert_expand     +menu              +multi_byte        -python            +statusline        +timers            +windows
-autoservername    +comments          +ex_extra          +ipv6              +mksession         +multi_lang        +python3           -sun_workshop      +title             +writebackup
+balloon_eval      +conceal           +extra_search      +job               +modify_fname      -mzscheme          +quickfix          +syntax            +toolbar           +X11
+balloon_eval_term +cryptv            -farsi             +jumplist          +mouse             +netbeans_intg     +reltime           +tag_binary        +user_commands     -xfontset
+browse            +cscope            +file_in_path      +keymap            +mouseshape        +num64             +rightleft         -tag_old_static    +vartabs           +xim
-builtin_terms     +cursorbind        +find_in_path      +lambda            +mouse_dec         +packages          -ruby              -tag_any_white     +vertsplit         +xpm
+byte_offset       +cursorshape       +float             +langmap           -mouse_gpm         +path_extra        +scrollbind        -tcl               +virtualedit       +xsmp_interact
+channel           +dialog_con_gui    +folding           +libcall           -mouse_jsbterm     +perl              +signs             +termguicolors     +visual            +xterm_clipboard
+cindent           +diff              -footer            +linebreak         +mouse_netterm     +persistent_undo   +smartindent       +terminal          +visualextra       -xterm_save
+clientserver      +digraphs          +fork()            +lispindent        +mouse_sgr         +popupwin          -sodium            +terminfo          +viminfo
   system vimrc file: "/zzz/etc/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "$VIM/gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
2nd user gvimrc file: "~/.vim/gvimrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/zzz/share/vim"
```

vim `:version`

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Jul 31 2021 22:05:17)
Included patches: 1-3172
Modified by morr@NetBSD.org
Compiled by willsk@ch12ldbld04
Huge version with GTK3 GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               +clipboard         +dnd               +gettext           +listcmds          -mouse_sysmouse    +postscript        -sound             +termresponse      +vreplace
+arabic            +cmdline_compl     -ebcdic            -hangul_input      +localmap          +mouse_urxvt       +printer           +spell             +textobjects       +wildignore
+autocmd           +cmdline_hist      +emacs_tags        +iconv             -lua               +mouse_xterm       +profile           +startuptime       +textprop          +wildmenu
+autochdir         +cmdline_info      +eval              +insert_expand     +menu              +multi_byte        -python            +statusline        +timers            +windows
-autoservername    +comments          +ex_extra          +ipv6              +mksession         +multi_lang        +python3           -sun_workshop      +title             +writebackup
+balloon_eval      +conceal           +extra_search      +job               +modify_fname      -mzscheme          +quickfix          +syntax            +toolbar           +X11
+balloon_eval_term +cryptv            -farsi             +jumplist          +mouse             +netbeans_intg     +reltime           +tag_binary        +user_commands     -xfontset
+browse            +cscope            +file_in_path      +keymap            +mouseshape        +num64             +rightleft         -tag_old_static    +vartabs           +xim
-builtin_terms     +cursorbind        +find_in_path      +lambda            +mouse_dec         +packages          -ruby              -tag_any_white     +vertsplit         +xpm
+byte_offset       +cursorshape       +float             +langmap           -mouse_gpm         +path_extra        +scrollbind        -tcl               +virtualedit       +xsmp_interact
+channel           +dialog_con_gui    +folding           +libcall           -mouse_jsbterm     +perl              +signs             +termguicolors     +visual            +xterm_clipboard
+cindent           +diff              -footer            +linebreak         +mouse_netterm     +persistent_undo   +smartindent       +terminal          +visualextra       -xterm_save
+clientserver      +digraphs          +fork()            +lispindent        +mouse_sgr         +popupwin          -sodium            +terminfo          +viminfo
   system vimrc file: "/zzz/etc/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "$VIM/gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
2nd user gvimrc file: "~/.vim/gvimrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/zzz/share/vim"
```

Comment: From that output, it looks like `inits 3` is only taking a few microseconds while `starting GUI` is the one taking so much time. Are `vim` and `gvim` different executables? Can we see the output of `:version` in both?

Comment: thank you @romainl. you are right, it's ```starting GUI``` being slow. I just updated my question and pasted the output of  ```:version``` of both. They seem the same